# resize div with resizing content in that div jquery

Tags: jquery, image, resize

I want to resize div. This div contains image. I want to resize image when div resize.
is it possible?
if its posible can anybody pls help me to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i created an example hope it helped.

http://jsfiddle.net/kHunM/

the image is big and it adjust to its container so if you want to have it on original size set the div width and height to the image size.